# Unity Angle Between Positions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I am currently working on an Among Us clone.
I was working on a venting system where the arrows (to navigate through the vents) are pointing in a completely wrong direction.

The arrow-prefab is just an empty object with the sprite as a child with its position changed along the forward axis.

```
Vector3 targetDir = myVent.transform.position - nextVent.transform.position;
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, Vector3.SignedAngle(myVent.transform.position, targetDir, Vector3.forward), 0);
```

The Whole Scene:
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7RQE.png)

How the Arrow Prefab looks like:
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxUbe.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Please include enough information to reproduce the problem including information such as the positions of each element in the scene as well as what the sprites look like without any rotation. See [mre] for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cross products to find the forward direction the transform should be, then use [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) to set the rotation:

```
Vector3 right = nextVent.transform.position - myVent.transform.position;

Vector3 forward = Vector3.Cross(right.normalized, Vector3.up);

transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(forward);
```